# I forgot to set username and password during Windows 7 installation, what can I do now?

Tags: windows-7

I have reinstalled Windows 7 but I forgot to set any user name and password during the setup. Now I want to create a standard user account for my sister, does this mean I have to reinstall the Windows 7 again?

Comment: Give me one second. I can help you out.

Comment: Refer to this question and its answer : http://superuser.com/questions/135868/creating-limited-user-account-on-windows-7

Comment: As far as I can recall, if you set up no User account at install on Win 7, then what you have actually set up is the 'Administrator' account with no password - which is unsafe. You need to first give it a good password, then set yourself up a new admin account, & also add a standard user for your sister.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to reinstall, Go to control panel user accounts and select manage another account there you can see create a new account. While creating you can select administrator or standard account according to your wish.